# Bootstrap's Javascript Button does not show Knockout observable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want the text in a bootstrap javascript button to be updated to show a number that is kept in a knockout observable in my viewmodel.

I can update the text on the button to be anything except an observable, when I change it to contain the observable, the button text is not correct and displays the observable as a function.

It's easier to explain with a fiddle so here is a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/rswailes/JxHwy/

HTML

```
<button
    id="download-file"
    data-loading-text="Updating totals..."
    data-bind="attr: {'data-complete-text' : 'Download lines: '+total , 
                      'data-finished-text' : 'done' }"
    autocomplete="off"
    class="btn btn-small download-file"
    type="button">Download file</button>

<p>
Total: <span data-bind="text: total"></span>
</p>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.total = ko.observable();

    this.loadModel = function(){
        $('#download-file').button("loading");
        this.total(10);
        $('#download-file').button("complete");   // this is the line I would like to work but does not work
        //$('#download-file').button("finished"); // if you uncomment this line you will see this line works fine
    };
};


viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.loadModel();
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if what I would like to do is possible?

EDIT: I have tried `total()` as suggested below, then I get "`Download lines: undefined`" on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of an observable, you need to call it as a function like `total()`.

The built-in bindings will take care of doing this for you, if you just pass a simple property/observable like `total`.  However, if you use it in an expression, then you would need to call it as a function yourself like `"Download lines: " + total()`

Comment: I did try that, then I get "undefined" instead of the function text. I'll update my question.

Comment: Bootstrap's button caches the original data- value and so it doesn't use your new value.  For example, if the original value was 5: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pcTsu/

Comment: I'm accepting this one because total() is correct but you also explain why the original data value gets kept.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `total()` for accessing the observable variable's value. And you have to update your code and use click binding to load your model data. Here's a working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/JxHwy/3/

Comment: I had tried using total before and got "undefined" on the button. Thank you for pasting the working fiddle. Can you explain why, if I move the $('#download-file').button("loading") to the line before this.total(10) then I get the "undefined" again? (This is closer to the code that I have in my real app).

Comment: I think I may know - you should be using `.text("complete")` and `.text("loading")`, if you are trying to change the button text, not `.button()` to do that.